# MDC value getting cleared - zipwih method

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, mdc

I have a weird situation. I'm using webflux+MDC for logging.

My method does fetch a flux from db and then zips it with the another value from another table.

Now with this, the MDC is correctly propogated and I can see that in logs also.

But if I run the se request again (without server restart) after zip, MDC is somehow is returning null.

Any help is much appreciated.